# How to add a counter element to *each* recurring value in a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, counter

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[('bike', '1'), ('bike', '2'), ('car', '3'), ('car', '4')]
```

and I want to count each time the first element appears and append it to the end of the tuple

```
[('bike', '1', '1'), ('bike', '2', '2'), ('car', '3', '1'), ('car', '4', '2')]
```

I have researched methods like counter, but it appears that only works to count the total amount of times an item appears. I have also found other methods that only seem to work for lists and not tuples.

Comment: *"I have also found other methods that only seem to work for lists and not tuples."*, is there any reason you need it to be a tuple or could you convert it to a list and back into a tuple? Furthermore, if 'bike' appears twice, wouldn't the first item be: `['bike', '1', '2']`?

Comment: You **do not** have tuples in your code.

Comment: If I try to convert it to a list I get 'tuple object is not callable'. I would not know how to convert it to a list otherwise

Comment: You say you have a list of tuples, but your example shows a tuple of lists. What method that seemed to work for lists but not for tuples did you try? What happened?

Comment: Ok fixed the question so they're actually tuples

Comment: Why does this post have negative 2 points? It asks a question and it is neatly answered. It is objectively a good post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the running count, you could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('bike', '1'), ('bike', '2'), ('car', '3'), ('car', '4')]

result = []
counts = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
for ele in data:
    k, v = ele
    result.append((k, v, counts[k]))
    counts[k] = counts[k] + 1

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('bike', '1', 1), ('bike', '2', 2), ('car', '3', 1), ('car', '4', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have a list of tuples
you can just loop over the data in the list, move it to another list and check the new list if it have that elem.